# How can I add or/and modify a version-number in Vimrc autocmd

Tags: vim, autocmd

I love to work with Vim. I use the autocmd in ~.vimrc like:

```
  :fun LastMod()
  :  if line("$") > 20
  :    let l = 20
  :  else
  :    let l = line("$")
  :  endif
  :  exe "1," . l . "g/Last modified: /s/Last modified: .*/Last modified: " .
  :  \ strftime("%Y %b %d")
  :endfun
```

The Question is:
**How can I add or/and modify a version-number** like:

from
Version: v1.34**5**
to 
Version: v1.34**6**

In action when I write a shell-Script, I like to automaticly modify some Lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Last modified: <date time>
# Version: v1.23-<n>
#
```

(maybe thats a little more clear)

Comment: Unclear! Whats or/and

Comment: For what it's worth, here's an equivalent rewrite of your function: `:%s/\m\%<21l^Last modified: \zs.*/\=strftime('%Y %b %d')/`.

Comment: your buffer has just the `v1.345`?  can you show some sample text?  There could be easier way

Comment: what I mean is:

in a script like:

#!/bin/bash
# Last modified: <date time>
# Version: v1.23<#>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I mean is: in a script like: #!/bin/bash # Last modified:  # Version: v1.23<#>

I think you want to change the version in your shell script(s). Assume that you have:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Last modified: whatever
#Version: v1.234
#other stuff
...
```

You can have this line in your `.vimrc`:

```
let @v="gg/Version:/\<cr>2E\<c-a>"
```

Then everytime you open your shellscript, pressing `@v` will make the version number be incremented by 1. Well the `1` means for example, from `v1.1099` to `v1.1100`

In fact it created a macro.

Comment: Thanks for successfully explaining the macro-function. I have tryed it out and it works fine.

But isn't there a way to make it automaticly like the "Last modified: "-function?

Comment: @amaz1ng, you can make the two modifications in one macro.

Answer (score 2):

Edit to match the sample you posted:

```
:%s/\m\%<21l^# Last modified: \zs.*/\=strftime('%Y %b %d')/
:%s/\m\%<21l^# Version: v\d\+\.\d\+-\zs\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/
```

Comment: ah, great. this works, too. \\ a very nice RegEx, like it ;)